# Does ROS optimize around unheard messages?

Tags: ros, optimization, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS on a system with low resources.

If I have a publisher streaming messages to a ROS topic (here, a topic which carries sonar readings), but the topic has no listeners, does ROS handle that data?  Or is it moved to temporary storage?  What extra load, if any, does the publishing of message introduce to the system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12515/does-ros-optimize-around-unheard-messages?/) by [luckyeights](https://answers.ros.org/users/1601/luckyeights/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-01-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The main overhead is you filling/creating the message + marshalling.
If you want to avoid your work: You can check for the `getNumSubscribers` property in a publisher to prevent doing any work (This is done, for example, in the kinect driver).

Messages should not be stored temporarily unless the topic is latched.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3